# Menu overlflow button on device with softkey buttons

Tags: android

my application looks like this on my galaxy nexus:

[image]
How can I add the menu overflow button to my softkey buttons on the bottom?
Or is this the way it is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to manually add any button to soft key bar. When there is soft key bar at the bottom, ActionBar will add menu button at the top (as in your example - 3 dots button). If you need support for SDK<11, use ActionBarSherlock lib.

Answer (score 0):

The menu menu button at the bottom where the soft keys are only appear when apps that have a menu but are built on older versions of android and they have not updated it yet to use the new actionbar menu.

In short no you cannot and users do not like when the menu button is in the soft key area because not all devices have soft keys so there will be a random black bar at the bottom of your screen just for the menu button.

Look here about [menu's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)